# How to calculate cumulative distance based on conditions with python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to create a function to calculate cumulative distance between a series of points based on a single condition of turning angles of trajectories.

I have this data frame:

```
Angles    X            Y
0   31   4998.872312  4999.736384
1  141   4996.074556  4994.330197
2  165   4995.919598  4996.283818
3  111   4994.775280  4997.525601
4    3   4994.571901  4997.657339
5   52   4994.704205  4998.305167
6    8   4994.556128  4997.754298
7   24   4994.495547  4997.832622
8  131   4994.515687  4997.796342
9   14   4994.317693  4997.944555
10  123  4993.723428  4998.392888
11  130  4994.218761  4998.585772
12  111  4994.250658  4998.735338
```

As long as ‘Angles’ is >  90, the function should create a list of the measured cumulative distance between following points determined through X and Y coordinates. When ‘Angles’ is </= 90, it stops and repeat the operation all along the data frame. (As in the example, I would like to calculate the cum distance between points 1 and 3, then between points 10 and 12, and so on…)

I have an idea of function in words that could be translated on a proper python script:

```
if df(Angles) > 90:
calculate cumulative distance between (X, Y) and (X+1,Y +1)
else:
stop and continue further in the dataframe
```

Could some one help me? Many thanks

Comment: Please provide the exact matching expected output and, ideally, a breakdown of the computation for the first few rows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calculate_cumulative_distance(df):
    cumulative_distances = []
    current_distance = 0
    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        if df['Angles'][i] > 90:
            x_dist = df['X'][i+1] - df['X'][i]
            y_dist = df['Y'][i+1] - df['Y'][i]
            distance = np.sqrt(x_dist**2 + y_dist**2)
            current_distance += distance
        else:
            if current_distance > 0:
                cumulative_distances.append(current_distance)
                current_distance = 0
    if current_distance > 0:
        cumulative_distances.append(current_distance)
    return cumulative_distances
```

According to your description wrote this function.

This will return a cumulative distance for each segment, where the angle is > 90 degrees and restarts if it encounters <= 90 degrees.